# Why is php cgi loaded in path when doing a 'sudo su <user>" vs just being logged in which uses php cli?

Tags: linux, command-line, php, sudo

When logged in as root user, php loads the correct version which is php cli.

[image]

But when i do a **sudo su < user >**, php is is loading the cgi version which is breaking some of my applications that require php-cli version.

[image]

I tried changing the php-cgi to php-cli, but that just totally broke all my websites as I believe my cms websites require php-cgi to run properly.

How do I make php-cli as the default program when i do a **sudo su user** or **sudo -i**?

Answer (score 0):

`SUDO SU user` only makes **SU** run as root, not the commands you execute in the context of the user.
To force php to be executed as root, you need to use `SUDO php`, and the user also need to be added to sudoers.
From a security perspective, I would not recommend the last part if the user is the same as the one running your CMS.

To allow the user **pat** to use `SUDO php`, add this to the end of sudoers with `SUDO visudo`:

```
# Allow the user pat to (sudo) execute /usr/local/bin/php
# as root without requiring user authentication.
pat ALL = NOPASSWD: /usr/local/bin/php
```

If the user **pat** is not the same user running your CMS, you could add **pat** to a group that has execute rights for `/usr/local/bin/php`.

If **pat** has execute rights and it's still not working, then make sure that **pat** has `/usr/local/bin` before `/usr/bin` in PATH.